# How to kill a process within a thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, signals

Ok, Class A is the Thread. Class B does the call. I tried to kill more than one process (tor, and a firefox) created inside the thread but seems that signals can only be send throught the main thread, so it failed, It says:

```
signal only works in main thread
```

I don't really understand threads well...

```
import subprocess
from threading import Thread

class A(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        # CREATE TWO PROCESSES
        subprocess.call(['tor'], shell=True)
        subprocess.call(['firefox'], shell=True)

        # ... stuff to get the pid of each process ...

        # KILL'EM (the failing part)
        subprocess.call(['kill -9 5431'], shell=True)
        subprocess.call(['kill -9 5432')], shell=True)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        x = A()
        x.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    B()
```

I don't know if it could be done with an RLock. Acquire, then call the `subprocess.call` with the signal and release to continue with the thread execution... Or if there's a better solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: You could use `Process` instead of `Thread`.

Comment: You've got problems well before you get to the signalling part. `subprocess.call(['tor'], shell=True)` executes the program and waits for it to complete. You can't get its pid afterwards because its already DOA.

Comment: Also, nothing in the example will result in "signal only works in main thread". You may be confused about how `signal.signal` works... it registers a signal handler, it doesn't send signals to other processes. For that, use `os.kill` or one of the methods on a Popen object.

Comment: Are you trying to kill processes that you created in the thread or processes that happen to be running outside of your python script? One challenge is that some programs like firefox may simply signal an existing instance of firefox to do its work and exit immediately.

Comment: It's a pseudocode, I'll start the tor process with `stem` library, that returns a `subprocess.Popen` It also creates the pidfile for every process. But the question was more on how to handle the thread to "switch" to the main thread  or how to pause/resume the current one  and then do the subprocess.call there...

Comment: I'm saying signal to refer to the kill parameter, that accepts a signal -9 is a SIGKILL -15 is a SIGTERM and so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can kill processes you created by using the `terminate` (graceful) and `kill` methods of the `Popen` object. Some programs like firefox tend to return immediately, so this doesn't always work. But the general idea is:

```
import subprocess
import threading

def kill_this(procs, hard=False):
    """kill the Popen processes in the list"""

    for proc in procs:
        if hard:
            proc.kill()
        else:
            proc.terminate()

class A(threading.Thread):
    """Runs tor and firefox, with graceful termination in 10 seconds and
    a hard kill in 20 seconds as needed"""

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        # create processes
        tor = subprocess.Popen(['tor'])
        firefox = subprocess.Popen(['firefox'])

        # setup timers to kill 'em 
        soft = threading.Timer(10, kill_this, ((tor, firefox), False))
        hard = threading.Timer(20, kill_this, ((tor, firefox), True))

        # wait for process exit
        tor.wait()
        firefox.wait()

        soft.cancel()
        hard.cancel()
```

Alternately, you can use system calls to get the pid of the process you want to kill and then convert `kill_this` to use a different API:

```
import subprocess
import threading
import signal

def kill_this(procs, hard=False):
    """kill the process pids in the list"""

    for proc in procs:
        if hard:
            os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)
        else:
            proc.terminate(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: Though that It'll work but I'm still getting the `signal only works in main thread` message with the two implementations (popen and signals) no matter if using kill or terminate. Could you explain me the `Timer` part ? The processes will wait n seconds to get closed when the `.wait()` method is triggered ? If `.cancel()` is triggered they won't be closed ? I've understood it correctly ?

Comment: What line are you getting `signal only works in main thread` on? Is it in my program or is it in a different place where you call `signal.signal(...)`?

Comment: You said that you wanted to create processes in a thread and then kill them. I assumed you wanted to wait a bit before killing them (otherwise, why create them) so I showed you a technique where you can delay before the termination (the first Timer which just runs the function in a separate thread after a timeout), kill if its not cooperative (the second Timer) or end immediately if they exit of their own accord (the waits).